# I have an APNG and I'm trying to set it as my background image, but the image does not cover the whole background fully

Tags: html, css

I have an APNG I'm trying to set as a background. I'm using the attribute [ background-image: URL('APNG.png') ]. However, its dimensions don't exactly match the dimensions of the screen window. Consequently, the image ends up being really small or it ends up being too big and clipped. How do I set up my background-image so that it covers the entire background. I am fine with the image being stretched. I just need it to fill up the background at all times without repeat.

Thanks for your help.
Sriram

Answer (score 2):

Use the CSS [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) property along with your `background-image`. Example below:

```css
img {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.example {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  
  /* the original image has a size of: 100x100 */
  background-image: url('https://web.archive.org/web/20080420192652im_/http://people.mozilla.com/~dolske/apng/spinfox.png');
}

.ex-1 {
  background-size: 100% 100%; /* or use "contain|cover|auto|....." */
}

.ex-2 {
  background-size: contain;
}

.ex-3 {
  background-size: cover;
}

.ex-4 {
  background-size: auto;
}
```

```html
<p>Original image</p>
<div><img src="https://web.archive.org/web/20080420192652im_/http://people.mozilla.com/~dolske/apng/spinfox.png" /></div>
<hr />
<p>background-size: 100% 100%</p>
<div class="example ex-1"></div>
<hr />
<p>background-size: contain</p>
<div class="example ex-2"></div>
<hr />
<p>background-size: cover</p>
<div class="example ex-3"></div>
<hr />
<p>background-size: auto</p>
<div class="example ex-4"></div>
```

Comment: What if you wanted to put it on a background that was 200x100 pixels. How do I make the png cover the entire background (even if it has to stretch). That was my main problem. My png does not fit the dimensions of the screen perfectly. I could change the dimensions of the png and make it more rectangular. However, it has been photoshopped heavily and that would mean changing the compositions added entirely. Is there a way to make the background-image stretch and cover the entire window at all times, displaying the image in its entirety at all instances?

Comment: @inurudum, I have updated the examples in the response for you. For full stretching, you need to use `background-size: 100% 100%` . But if you need to leave the proportions of the background image, I recommend taking a closer look at `background-size: contain` and `background-size: cover` taking into account the positioning of the background using `background-position`. In the example they are presented.

Comment: Thank you so much Oleg. I wish I could like your comment or give it an upvote but I don't have any points or whatever. Happy new year by the way and I hope you have a great 2022 :)